# In R, How can I compare two continuous variables and indicating two categorical variables in a chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

For example, lets say I want a plot that compares cost and score of two age groups, and the plot should also indicate their gender.

What plot can I use and how can each attribute be distinguished?

Comment: try a boxplot. its used for comparing continuous and categorical variables

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ggplot2`.

E.g. using the mtcars data:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, shape = factor(vs), size = cyl)) + geom_point()
```